# What does "that" refer to?

Tags: meaning

Alexei says to his wife, whose behavoir is improper at horse racing:

> Alexei: Your conduct was improper. It must not occur again. I have said it before.
> You will say my concern is unnecessary and ridiculous. You are my wife.
> I'm wrong to think **that**.

What does "that" refer to?

Comment: It's a rather odd way of saying things, but it looks as though "that" is intended to refer to "my concern is unnecessary and ridiculous".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You will say ..." supposes that his wife will speak like this:

> *Wife*: Alexei, your concern is unnecessary and ridiculous. I am your wife. You are wrong to think that [my conduct was improper].